# App.yaml - Single URL to Serve Multiple Static Directories

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible on app engine (python) to point multiple static directories to a single url?  In my app.yaml file I'm hoping to do something like:

ATTEMPT 1:

```
 - url: /media/
   static_dir: static/.*
```

ATTEMPT 2:

```
 - url: /media/
   static_dir: static/dir1

 - url: /media/
   static_dir: static/dir2
```

ATTEMPT 3:

```
 - url: /media/
   static_dir: static/dir1
   static_dir: static/dir2
```

Using the anything notation (.*) results in both directories not working.  The multiple declaration in Attempt 2 results in only the first one working (dir1) and the second one (dir2) being ignored.  Attempt 3 results in a warning when I try to run the engine and allow for it to be run locally.

How can I do this without changing the url for each new static directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want everything under 'static' to serve via '/media' it should work just fine as:

```
 - url: /media
   static_dir: static
```

EDIT - At the time I'm writing this, this exact configuration is used here:
https://imaginaryboy.appspot.com/media/dir1/text.txt

Comment: I don't love this solution because my URL paths will have an extra level before getting to the dir1 or dir2 folders, but not a bad suggestion...It's too bad it's not possible to do exactly what I was asking (per Dmitry Sadovnychyi's response).  Marking this as the answer since I'll proceed this way.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. But you can make it work with links like /media-1/img.jpg, /media-2/bla.jpg, etc.

```
- url: /media-(.*?)/(.*)
  static_files: static/dir\1/\2
  upload: static/(.*?)/(.*)
```

More at [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers).

I think that the only way out is to use simple build script, which will copy all images from /static/dir1 and /static/dir2 into media. You can use this script for one-click deployment as well. Something like this:

```
import os, glob
source = ['static/dir-1', 'static/dir-2']
dest = 'media'
for s in source:
  for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(s, '*.*')):
    shutil.copy(f, dest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is a great point and I appreciate the reference.  I'm going to implement 'imaginaryboy's solution for now (due to simplicity), but in the long run I'll likely do something more like this.  Thanks!